# WM_CONCAT use CASE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a select:

```
select substr(acc,1,4)
       ,currency
       , amount
       , module
       , count(*)
       , wm_concat(trn_ref_no) trn  
from all_entries 
where date = to_date ('01012010','DDMMYYYY')
group by substr(acc,1,4),currency, amount, module
```

In this case I get an error:
 `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: : character string buffer too small ... "WMSYS.WM_CONCAT_IMPL"`

To avoid buffer limit error I changed it to:

```
select substr(acc,1,4)
        ,currency
       , amount
       , module
      , count(*)
      , (case when count(*) < 10 then wm_concat(trn_ref_no) else null end) trn  
from fcc.acvw_all_ac_entries 
where trn_dt = to_date ('05052010','DDMMYYYY')
group by substr(acc,1,4),currency, amount, module
```

But even in this case i have the same error.   How can i avoid this error?

Comment: isn't this rather similar to what you asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558771/charater-string-buffer-too-small

Answer (score 3):

WM_CONCAT returns a VARCHAR2, and so is constrained to a maximum of 4000 characters in SQL.  You could write your own string aggregate function that returned a CLOB if you need more than that.  However, it may be better to think about why you are doing this, and whether there isn't a better way altogether - e.g. using the 10G COLLECT function to return a collection.

See [this article on string aggregation techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php) for how you might write your own aggregate function.

Comment: collection is good, but i do this select in SQL Nagivagor and afterward i export to Excel the result, and in this case collections are not exported properly

Comment: Then I think you will have to accept the limitation that this solution is only good for a limited number of concatenated values.  But it can be a lot more than 10 most likely - find the maximum number that are sure to fit within 4000 characters when concatenated.